# Reporting in Rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

I can't find the reports plus in my Rhapsody v8.1.2 x64
anybody knows the reason.

I also need to make custom profile to generate documents out of the design. I am thinking of using the ModelBasedDocumentGeneration profile but I can't find any help how to use it.

I'd appropriate if any one can recommend something (materials or another way to make the reports)
P.S. I don't have Rational Publishing Engine

Comment: Do you have "Rhapsody ReporterPLUS" in "Start > All Programs > IBM Rational > IBM Rational Rhapsody *version*"?

Comment: Have you tried the 32bit version? Some features/plugins are indeed missing in the 64bit version. If you have the choice, I would propose to use the 32bit version.

Comment: You are totally correct. This is one of the missing features in 64 version. Thanks Sergei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the missing features in the 64 version according to this link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038779